# PHP: Extract text from string between two specific tags

Tags: php, html, tags, extract

I'm putting together a quick extracting function in PHP. Basically, it will read the contents of a given URL and extract the necessary HTML code. It will then put the code into a new page. Now, I've gotten everything working except one thing.

I have a string with the contents of the URL, and now I want to extract text between two tags.
Let's say I want to start copying content at a certain  tag. That's easy since those tags have classes.

So I'd have the function start with "" It simply searches the document for all text that matches this. I've run into a problem, though. Within the section I wish to copy, there are other  tags. As such, if I tell the function to stop extracting at "," the scraper will stop reading at the end of a random  tag. Can someone help me write a bit of PHP code that will ensure that the  tag the function stops at is the closing tag for the "" and not for some random  tag that happens to be in the string?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Why do people love Cthulhu so much?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/871050)

Comment: duplicate of about 10 trillion other S.O questions.

Comment: PHP FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do this and account for every possible content between the tags. Use `XmlDocument` and parse the HTML.